# Callback limit Node.JS? Or am I missing something?

Tags: node.js, callback

Good day, I recently had help learning how to make things wait using callbacks, however now it's almost as if I hit a limit on how many can be used, but I can't seem to find information on this?

If I ran this code without tryToCreateAccount having a callback, it will connect, check and work as intended. As soon as I make tryToCreateAccount have a callback param, it appears to enter Connect.Connect (only sometimes) but then never query's.

**Backend:**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'host',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'db'
});

export function tryToCreateAccount(login, password, passwordConfirm, callback) 
{
    checkAccountNameAvailable(login, connection, function(err, accountNameAvailable)
    {
        callback(err, accountNameAvailable);
    });

}

function checkAccountNameAvailable(login, connection, callback)
{
    var accountNameAvailable = true;

    console.log("Checking account name", login);
    connection.connect(function (err)
    {
        console.log("Checking Connect Method");
        if(err) callback(err);
        connection.query("SELECT login FROM accounts WHERE login = ?", login, function (err, result)
        {
            if (err) callback(err);
            if(result.length > 0) accountNameAvailable = false;
            console.log("returning ", accountNameAvailable);
            callback(null, accountNameAvailable);
            connection.end();
        });
    });
}
```

**Front End:**

```
 tryToCreateAccount($w('#input1').value, $w('#input2').value, $w('#input3').value, function (err, callback)
        {
            if(callback)
            {
                console.log("Was True");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Was False");
            }
        });
```

**UPDATED CODE:
Backend:**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const pool = mysql.createPool(
{
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host            : 'host',
    user            : 'user',
    password        : 'pass',
    database        : 'db'
});

export function tryToCreateAccount(login, password, passwordConfirm, callback) 
{
    checkAccountNameAvailable(login, pool, function(err, accountNameAvailable)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err, null);
        }

        callback(err, accountNameAvailable);
    });

}

function checkAccountNameAvailable(login, pool, callback)
{
    var accountNameAvailable = true;

    console.log("Checking account name", login);

    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection)
    {
        console.log("Made a connection.");

        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err, null);
            connection.destroy();
        }

        connection.query("SELECT login FROM accounts WHERE login = ?", login, function (err, result)
        {
            console.log("Checking Query Method");

            if (err)
            {
                console.log(err);
                callback(err, null);
            }

            if(result.length > 0) accountNameAvailable = false;
            console.log("returning ", accountNameAvailable);
            callback(null, accountNameAvailable);
            connection.destroy();
        });
    });

}
```

Frontend is the same

**Output:**

```
Checking account name testaccount
```

Comment: Do you get the `console.log("Checking Connect Method");` line?
Maybe you want to add `if(err){ console.log(err); callback(err);}` instead of just `callback(err)`

Comment: Also I may have led you a little bit astray in terms of where `const connection =` should be. If you want to make a connection per function call place it back inside your `tryToCreateAccount` function, although I highly recommend using the `pool` functionality

Comment: @CodyＧI sometimes get the Checking Connect Method log, not always. I'll move it into the  try to connect function and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @CodyＧ - Moving the const connection made no change, so I switched to pool and moved it to the outside again.

I added new code to the original question, still not working.

Comment: You always get the `"Checking account name"` log though?

Comment: @CodyＧ "checking account name" is every time. sometimes, but definitely not very often, it will also say "Made a connection" but only like 1 in 50 attempts if I'm lucky.

Comment: If that's the case, like I said, try logging your errors (`err`)

Comment: @CodyＧI thought I had console logs for all the errors already in the latest updated code.

Comment: I left tryToCreateAccount with a callback, and added a function inside the backend code that calls it and only takes in the login name and does not provide a call back. The issue seems to be trying to pass the callback to the front-end it just doesn't work. As long as no callback to the front end occurs it all works as intended.. I'm not sure why.

Comment: It basically prevents the backend from interacting with the front end at all, whether its a callback, or if I pass in objects from the front end, trying to Hide/Show them locks it up as well.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're doing with "front end" and "back end". Node.js is completely backend unless you're using some sort of server-side rendering framework

Comment: @CodyＧthat may be what my issue is and what I'm not understanding. I'm using Wix Platform for web development. I'm trying to use Node.JS to add functionality for a game server I'm creating to allow users to create accounts on the website. They offer something called .jsw (their web module) that lets you export functions for use on the front end. I'm thinking this has a limitation however to prevent any data from leaving the backend (ie: my callbacks, etc). I'm just not sure how I'll pass a confirmation that the account was created to the front end when it try's to create account.

Comment: I briefly looked at some documentation ... and yep you're actually dealing with server-side calls from the front end. Useful, but a little wacky to jump into immediately.

Comment: My suggestion is that you try really really basic callback/promise/async functions to prove to yourself their code works in various cases and then move back to implementing your sql code. You might find the callback styled architecture is somehow messing with their "Velo handles all the client-server communication required to enable this access." and that you might need to export a promise instead.

Comment: @CodyＧappreciate it, yeah I might do that, I was just reading some documentation and if I was reading it correctly, it seems Promises may be the only data the Velo lets reach the front-end from the backend. Which isn't necessarily a bad thing, just means all my code would have to change hah. I may start with some basic promise checks for
Complete backend (.js) -> Inbetween (.jsw) -> Front End call. and see if I can get it to at least pass the promise back to the front end call. Cheers for your help.